# Find keyword in snake_case texts

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem where I need to find if a word(for example "output") is present in a snake_case word.

Which means the regex must be capable of matching all of the following situations-

- output
- output_of_my_program
- my_output_from_program
- program_output

i.e. output, output_, *output*, and _output need to be matched

currently I have three individual regex patterns to cover all the cases, which are-

- `"^output[^a-z]_?"`
- `"_output_"`
- `"_output$"`

I however have tried to combine the three into one, which is `[a-z]*_?[^a-z]output_?[a-z]*` but this fails for certain cases. Is it possible to combine the three patterns into one in this case?

Edit:The other keywords I am interested in are "in", "input", "out" and the challenge is to **avoid** matches with words such as "introspection" and other cases such as "my_programoutput"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't include it in your test cases, but I assume part of the intent is to explicitly *not* match a string like `my_floutputs_from_program`.  You could do this with a tricky regex, but I'd just use `split` and `in`:

```
for s in (
    'output', 
    'output_of_my_program', 
    'my_output_from_program', 
    'program_output', 
    'input', 
    'my_floutputs_from_program'
):
    print(f"{s}: {'output' in s.split('_')}")
```

```
output: True
output_of_my_program: True
my_output_from_program: True
program_output: True
input: False
my_floutputs_from_program: False
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why `'output' in s` would not work? You do not have to use regex to solve this, unless it is necessitated as part of the project.

```
>>> strings = [
...     'output',
...     'output_of_my_program',
...     'my_output_from_program',
...     'program_output',
...     'input'
... ]
>>>
>>> for s in strings:
...     print('output' in s)
...
True
True
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the re library, you can just use the search function with the string required to find.

```
import re

txt = "my_output_from_program"
result = re.search("output", txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pattern with either a word boundary, or a postive assertion for `_` on the left or the right if you don't want partial matches.

```
(?:\b|(?<=_))output(?:\b|(?=_))
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:\b|(?<=_))` Match either a word boundary or assert `_` to the left
- `output` Match literally
- `(?:\b|(?=_))` Match either a word boundary, or assert `_` to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RXJuw0/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BubwHp).

```
import re

pattern = r"(?:\b|(?<=_))output(?:\b|(?=_))"
strings = [
    "output",
    "output_of_my_program",
    "my_output_from_program",
    "program_output",
    "my_programoutput"
]

for s in strings:
    m = re.search(pattern, s)
    if m:
        print(f"{s} --> {m.group()}")
```

Output

```
output --> output
output_of_my_program --> output
my_output_from_program --> output
program_output --> output
```